# Add new component dynamically

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am in parent component and i am trying to add dynamically a new component by clicking a button. I will paste only the necessary code because my files are large.

So below its the lets say the parent component:

```
    export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            conditions: [{attribute: '', operator: '', value: ''}]
        }
    }

    addCondition = (e) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            conditions: [...prevState.conditions, { attribute: '', operator: '',value: '' }],
        }));
    }

    render() {
        let {conditions} = this.state
        return(
                <Row>
                    <TextButton label='Add Child' onClick={(e) => {this.addCondition}} flat={true} />
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <ChildElement conditions={conditions} />
                </Row>
            )
    }

}
```

And this is the ChildElement that i want to render dynamically:

```
export class ChildElement extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            attribute: '',
            operator: '',
            action: '',
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.conditions.map((val, idx)=> {
                let attributeId = `attributeId-${idx}`,
                    operatorId = `operatorId-${idx}`,
                    valueId = `valueId-${idx}`
                return (
                    <Row>
                        <Col >
                            <Dropdown id={attributeId}  />
                        </Col>
                        <Col >
                            <Dropdown id={operatorId}  />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Dropdown id={valueId} />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                );
            })
        );
    }
}
```

When parent component is loaded i get error:

```
Uncaught Error: ConditionElement.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the value in your `render` method of your child component in at least a `div`. Now you return an array of components.

I don't know which version of React you are using, but you could do:

```
return (
  <>
    { conditions.map( /* ... */ ) }
  </>
);
```

or

```
return (
  <div>
    { conditions.map( /* ... */ ) }
  </div>
);
```

if `<>` and `</>` are not supported in your version.

Comment: tried the div and get error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (40:4)

  38 |    <div>
  39 |    this.props.conditions.map((val, idx)=> {
> 40 |     let attributeId = `attributeId-${idx}`,

Comment: hm yes this does the trick. But the exact time that a new child element is added then it reloads the page

Comment: Hmmm... Strange. I guess this is not linked to your original question, but it is linked with something else in your code. Btw did you change your `onClick` prop as @larz suggested (i.e. to `onClick={this.addCondition}`). At least fixing this could as well help.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to get a wild guess here as i don't see the entire code.
You are importing the `ChildElement` as if it was a `default export` but actually it's a named export.

This

```
export class ChildElement
```

should be imported like that:

```
import {ChildElement} from './path'
```

And not:

```
import ChildElement from './path'
```

Comment: i am importing it with the { }

Comment: which one of them is the `ConditionElement` then?

Answer (score 1):

1 - you need to actually call the function in your onClick -
`onClick={(e) => {this.addCondition}}` should be either `onClick={(e) => {this.addCondition()}}` or `onClick={this.addCondition}`

2 - You need to wrap adjacent React components in a single parent (usually `<div>` or `<React.Fragment>`).